# How to transfer contacts in my outlook pst to Samsung Galaxy S II (or - any android phone)?

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I am having my contacts backed up in my outlook and now i will be able to export it to .pst and from that is it possible by any means to bring the contacts to my android phone (Samsung Galaxy S II) ??

Please help..

Kindly give me all the possible options

Comment: I am slightly inclined to think that these type of questions are really off topic. They are not really android related. Since the answer to these questions are ALWAYS a tool to sync outlook with your GOOGLE account, not the actual device.

Comment: To give the OP the benefit of the doubt, it's usually unclear to a new Android user that their devices sync to Google services.

Comment: I agree, which is why I didn't actually vote to close it or anything...

Answer (score 2):

The process is pretty straight-forward.

1. In Outlook, export your Contacts into a coma-delimited text file (.CSV).  Depending on the version of MS Outlook you are running, the location of this feature may be under a different menu item.
2. Open up a browser, go to Gmail and login with the same Google account you use on your Android phone.
3. Click on the "Contacts" link, then click on the "More actions" button and select the "Import" option.
4. Now navigate to wherever you have saved the CSV file from step 1 and select it.
5. After the import process completed, your Gmail account should now have all of your Outlook contacts.
6. On your Android phone ensure that your Google account is set to synchronize the contacts by going to Menu -> Settings -> Accounts & sync, selecting your Google account and ensuring that there is a checkmark next to "Contacts".
7. Also make sure you are allowing background data and auto-sync on the Previous screen.
8. Again tap on your Google account and un-check/re-check the box next to "Contacts" to force an immediate sync.
9. Wait several minutes and check the Contacts app - all of your exported contacts from Outlook should now be on your phone.

Keep in mind that this is a one-time, one-way sync.  If you want to have any changes you make in Outlook to automatically sync to your Android phone, you will need a 3rd-party application on your Windows machine that will auto-upload your changes to your Google account.

Answer (score 1):

Under `tools` there should be a `MessageSave` command that will allow you to export your contacts to a .vcf file, which you can put on your sd card and import from the contacts application on your phone.

[This](http://www.techhit.com/outlook/export_contacts_vcard_vcf.html) is a link to doing the same thing with the goal of exporting for Mac devices, but should work the same, and [this](http://www.techhit.com/outlook/export_contacts_vcard_vcf.html) is a detailed step by step to bulk export to a single vcard. Both should do the same thing, and both should get your contacts to your Android phone!

Answer (score 1):

[GO Contact Sync](http://jameslam.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/sync-contacts-between-microsoft-outlook-and-gmail/) will sync your contacts between your outlook and your Google account. your android device will then sync with your Google account and everything will be in sync.

You can probably find tools to sync your calendar as well, if you wanted to.